# VSCode not resolving system includes: how to properly direct VSCode to where system headers are located?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out how to direct VSCode to properly resolve those "system" or "angle bracket" styled includes vs double quote includes.

[image: angle bracket resolution failure]

I'm doing development somewhat in a partial cross compiler workflow where I'm using my Mac to do my code studies and navigation on a codebase built in linux. I made copies of the linux system headers (`/usr/include`) into a user folder and copied that path into the following vscode settings

```
"C_Cpp.default.systemIncludePath"
"C_Cpp.default.includePath"
"C_Cpp.default.browse.path"
```

What other settings should I possibly be looking at to get the angle bracket imports to resolve in VSCode? You can see in the image above that `#include "memory.h"` works while  `#include <memory>` does not and presents the red squiggles side by side. You can see the header can properly resolve just not with the angle bracket syntax.

[image: Problems tab showing 'include errors detected']